# How does our computer actually converts decimal number into binary?

Tags: binary, decimal

We know that computer performs its all operations in binary only. It cannot work with decimal or any other base numbers.
If computer cannot perform any operation in decimals, then how does it convert them to binary? I think there are different stages during the conversion at which addition and multiplication are required. How the computer can add or multiply any number even before getting its binary equivalent ?

I have searched this in many place but couldn't find a convincing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This stackexchange site is not the right place to ask this question. I am still answering it, better shift it to the appropriate one or delete question after getting your answer.

Well it doesn't care what input you supply to it. Think of it as your tv switch. When you switch it on, your tv starts to work. This happens because it got the exact current flow it required to work. Similarly in a computer, there is a particular voltage, let's say 5V. Below 5V is all considered what you call as '0' otherwise '1'. You may have seen an `AND`, `OR` etc gates. If you supply both '1' to `AND` it results in '1' otherwise '0'. There are many such digital circuits. Some examples are a binary adder, a latch, a flip flop etc. These work with these current signals (which are characterised as 0 or 1 as explained above). A computer is a combination of millions of such circuits.

When you talk about converting decimal to binary or something like that, its actually not like that. Every program (spreadsheets, games etc) are written in some language. Most common ones are compiled or interpreted. Some languages that get compiled are `C`, `java`etc. and some interpreted ones are `python`, `ruby`etc. Job of a compiler or interpreter if to convert the code you wrote in that language to assembly code as per the rules of that language. Assembly code is then converted into machine code when it has to run. Machine code is pure zeros and ones. These zeros and ones just define triggers on what to execute and when.

Don't confuse this with what you see. Desktop that displays you the data is a secondary thing that is specifically made just to make things easy for us.

In a computer a clock keeps running. Like you must have heard 2.5Ghz processor or something like that. This is the frequency with which instructions are executed. Seems odd but yes whether you are doing work or not, when computer is working, it executes instructions continuously and if you are not doing anything it keeps on checking for interaction.

Imagine correctly

1) you opened your pc, the hardware got ready for your commands and kept checking for interaction

2)you opened a folder. Now think to open a folder you obviously need to touch the keyboard, mouse or do some voice interaction. This interaction is followed by your computer. Pressing a down arrow produces a zero or one signal at the right place. Now after this it gets displayed to you. It is not that what is being displayed is being done. Instead what is being done is getting displayed for you to follow it easily.